# How to write a SQL request in less code?

Tags: mysql

I have a code like this:

```
SELECT 
  `cabinet`.`name_test`, 
  `answers`.`answer_id`,
  (
    SELECT `answer_id` 
    FROM `answers` 
    WHERE `user_id` = '353281' AND `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
  ) as answer_2
FROM `cabinet` 
INNER JOIN `answers`
WHERE
  `user_id` = '184918649' 
  AND `friend_id` = '353281' 
  AND `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
```

How not to write twice: `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`?

Comment: Why don't you want to write it twice? Is there a problem? Do you have a concern about something? If it were me I'd be more worried about the correlated subquery. Also it would help if you described your tables and what you are trying to do.

Comment: It will be twice to access the table?

Comment: You need two separate rows from the `answers` table. What's the problem with accessing the table twice? Are accesses expensive? Is there a limit on the number of accesses you are allowed to make? What are you concerned about? There's obviously something on your mind, but you haven't stated what it is.

Comment: Everything works as it should. But I think that we can write in less. Identical conditions except friend_id=353281 for the first user.

Comment: Yes but *why* do you want to write it in less code? Are keystrokes expensive in your organization? Do you feel that shorter code is always more readable? I'm trying to find out what your underlying motivation is for changing the query if it works fine already. Changes cost money. If you just want more readable code then ask for that instead of just specifying "less code".

Comment: Faster? OK, now we are getting somewhere... but you really should have made that more clear in the first place, IMHO. Why do you want it to be faster? Do you have a genuine performance problem or is it just out of curiousity? Do you know what indexes are for? Do you have any indexes defined on your tables? How many rows are there in each table? Can you please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for each table and also the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your query?

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i717/1212/a1/fe6dead77dbc.png

Comment: I can save the value in a variable? `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`. To 2 times not to request a table.

Comment: No, you can't. There are some things you could do to remove that duplication, but it would require *more* code not less. There are also some things that would help improve the performance of your query, but that isn't one of them. To be frank, the way the question is written it's impossible to help you while still answering the question. Any answer I post that would improve the performance would be completely unrelated to your requirement of "less code" and would be downvoted for not answering the question. Next time think carefully about what you are asking and **why** you are asking it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really less code, but you can also do this by joining on the `answers` table twice:

```
SELECT 
  c.`name_test`, 
  a1.`answer_id` answer_1,
  a2.`answer_id` answer_2
FROM `cabinet` c
INNER JOIN `answers` a1
  ON c.`test_id` = a1.`test_id`
  AND a1.`user_id` = '184918649' 
  AND  `friend_id` = '353281'
INNER JOIN `answers` a2
  ON c.`test_id` = a2.`test_id`
  AND a2.`user_id` = '353281'
```

Or you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  c.`name_test`, 
  a1.`answer_id` answer_1,
  a2.`answer_id` answer_2
FROM `cabinet` c
INNER JOIN
(
  select `answer_id`
  from `answers`
  where `user_id` = '184918649' 
    AND  `friend_id` = '353281'
) a1
  ON c.`test_id` = a1.`test_id`
INNER JOIN
(
  select `answer_id`
  from `answers`
  where `user_id` = '353281'
) a2
  ON c.`test_id` = a2.`test_id`;
```

Comment: Error #1052 - Column 'user_id' in on clause is ambiguous

Comment: @user1924058 see my edit, you need to preface the column with the table alias

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `ON` clause in your sql

try this

```
       SELECT 
  `cabinet`.`name_test`, 
   `answers`.`answer_id`,
  (
     SELECT `answer_id` 
    FROM `answers` 
     WHERE `user_id` = '353281' AND `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
   ) as answer_2
 FROM `cabinet` 
 INNER JOIN `answers` on `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
 WHERE

 `user_id` = '184918649' 
 AND `friend_id` = '353281'
```

removed the last line which is double

Comment: Actually in MySQL it's legal, and in this case correct (but slightly confusing) to omit the `ON` clause from an `INNER JOIN`.